# Knockout Conditional Formatting for Observable Number Not Working

Tags: javascript, html, css, knockout.js

I have a situation in which I'd like to conditionally format the background colour of a certain area based on the value of an object. In this case, it's a piece of furniture and its `serialNumber`. Of course, this is simplified, as really I would like a triple condition. Whether the value is 0,1,or 2, but I can't even get it working with a simpler condition.

No idea why it's not working. It seems as though it should be simple enough. Here's a fiddle for you:

http://jsfiddle.net/Lxh8e9qv/1/

**HTML**

```
<tr data-bind="foreach: furnitures" id="furnitureArea" data-bind="style: { backgroundColor: serialNumber > 1 ? 'red' : 'grey' }">
```

**JavaScript**

```
var Room = function (name, furnitures) {
  var self = this;
  self.name = ko.observable(name);
  self.furnitures = ko.observableArray([]);
  self.serialNumber = ko.observable();
  ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your HTML fragment you need to invoke the serialNumber function in the data-bind like so

`<tr data-bind="foreach: furnitures" id="furnitureArea" data-bind="style: { backgroundColor: serialNumber() > 1 ? 'red' : 'grey' }`

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lxh8e9qv/2/)

Or for a better solution, create a knockout computed function in the furniture viewmodel and move all your logic there.

```
var Furniture = function (data) {
    var self = this;
    self.name = ko.observable('');
    self.size = ko.observable('');
    self.serialNumber = ko.observable();
    self.rowStyle = ko.computed({
        read: function () {
            return self.serialNumber() > 1 ? 'red' : 'grey'';
        },
        deferEvaluation: true
    });

    if (typeof data !== 'undefined') {
        self.name(data.name);
        self.size(data.size);
        self.serialNumber(data.serialNumber);
    }
}
```

`<tr data-bind="foreach: furnitures" id="furnitureArea" data-bind="style: { backgroundColor: rowStyle}`

[Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lxh8e9qv/3/)

Comment: This is an excellent answer. Thank you. I suppose that by having the logic in the viewmodel would also allow for more complex conditions, such as changing the colour to green, yellow, or red for the `serialNumber` equalling 1, 2, or 3.

Comment: That's right.  Much better to have that type of logic in the view model. the view then just has to display the results.

Answer (score 1):

Missing `()`

```
<tr data-bind="foreach: furnitures" id="furnitureArea" data-bind="style: { backgroundColor: serialNumber() > 1 ? 'red' : 'grey' }">
```

When you want to deal with the observable value make sure you use `()`